# How to detect a string within an ArrayList with a for each loop?

Tags: java, arraylist, contains, instantiation

public String searchNumber(String name){
        String result = "";

```
    for(Person search: person){
        if(search.getName().contains(name)){
            result += search.getNumber();
        }
        else{
            result = " number not known ";
        }
    }
    return result;

}
```

Looking for some advice here on how to fix this problem I am having. This is a method which I expect to use my getName method to see if the local instance (name) is within the ArrayList. However, I am only getting the latter result to display only, saying "number not known." My step-by-step process goes like this: I create an instance of Person (search), access the getName method, access the contains method since it is originally a String method, and then check to see if the local instance is within the arrayList. If my logic is incorrect, please correct me. Also, does accessing the person array prevent me from using a String type in my for-each loop, since it is a Person object? I tried do this with a String type, but could not continue further since I could not convert to a String within the for-each loop.

Comment: Is there an issue other than the printing of " number not known "? Is the result returned as you want?

Comment: @ShivashriganeshMahato I only get that message returned. which should only be returned in the case the name is not found within the arrayList. I'm not sure if I wrote the condition correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a breakdown of your current code:

You consider every object in the `person` list. If that person's name matches the parameter, you get the number from it. Otherwise, you set `result` to the error message. Note that the otherwise clause is applied for EACH person, instead of at the end if NOBODY was found to have the same name. That is, even if you find the right person and assign `result` to their number, if the next person isn't correct then you overwrite `result` to the error message again.

To make sure the error message is only assigned once and only if NOBODY is found, you need to check whether that is true after going through everyone (since you can't know if nobody is found before checking everyone!). The trick now is to find some clause which is always true when nobody was found. But that can just be if `result` was never modified. That is, you can set `result` to the default value at declaration, then only modify it to a number if the right person was found. Also, I am assuming that only one person should be found and you don't want to actually concatenate the numbers together (which is what you are doing by using `+=`). That said, try this:

```
public String searchNumber(String name){
    for (Person search: person){
        if (search.getName().contains(name)){
            return search.getNumber();
        }
    }

    return " number not known ";
}
```

Comment: Yes, only the name from the local instance, when the method is called. If you don't mind, can you pin point what was particularly wrong with mine? I would appreciate it.

Comment: The main issue is that you had your else statement within the loop. Like I mentioned in my explanation, even if you found the correct person and updated `result` with their number, if the next person was wrong (which they most likely would be) then `result` would be overwritten with the error message again.

Comment: Why do you keep looping after you have found the `Person`.  If there are thousands of users this could be a bottleneck.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Very true, updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @ShivashriganeshMahato I see. I overlooked that there was no way to stop it, like a traditional loop. Thank you.

Comment: In your original implementation you also could've added a `break;` after modifying `result` when the correct name was found. That would accomplish the same thing. Just have to make sure to change `+=` to `=` as well, otherwise if it finds someone with the wrong name before it would return the error message with the number concatenated to it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can just return after finding your record

```
String notFound = " number not known ";
for(Person search: person){
    if(search.getName().contains(name)){
        return search.getNumber();
    }
}
return notFound;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String result = null;
for(Person search: person){
    if(search.getName().contains(name)){
        result += search.getNumber();
    }

}
if(result == null){
    result = "number not known ";
}
return result;
```

Since there is no way to tell the last element in for-in loop, so the alternative is basing on **result == null**